# Is there any way to save / remember position of the nodes of amchart force directed tree?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

Here is an example of amchart force directed tree https://www.amcharts.com/demos/force-directed-tree/

Is there any way to remember positions of all nodes and then after page refreshing show it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

To store and load any kind of data for a specific webpage, one of the most common ways is using the browser's LocalStorage api.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage